# Как сделать bootstrap dropdown(ниспадающее меню) без значка

Tags: вёрстка, bootstrap, веб-программирование, dropdown

Верстаю макет, использую Bootstrap, стоит задача сделать такой элемент:
[image: ниспадающее меню] Как использовать готовые элементы бутстрапа понятно, но я не могу понять как убрать значек рядом с dropdown. Он присутствует во всех подобных элементах бутстрапа.
 
[image: bootstrap dropdown]   
 В интеренете ответа на даный вопрос не нашел, может кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой, подскажите пожалуйста выход.
  П.С. понятно что можно самому сделать это на jQuery, но вопрос не в этом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задайте:

```
.caret { display: none; }
```